# How do I install JIRA-Dashboard in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jira

I am getting javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart errors when trying to add a server

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should install the JIRA Mylyn plugin for the recent versions of Eclipse, and not Dashboard.  I did that the other day and it worked out of the box (after enabling RPC in JIRA).